# Syspreping an Ubuntu image

Tags: 20.04, clone, disk-image

Is there a way to make a capture-ready Ubuntu image? something like Sysprep for Windows, where you remove all the user-specific data from the image (like user accounts, passwords, etc ...) to make a 'golden' universal image ready to be deployed on other computers.

Comment: What do you mean by "capture ready"?

Answer (score 0):

The most official method is probably `virt-sysprep`.  It is meant to be used on a shutdown virtual machine image, which is not always an option.  The [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/virt-sysprep.1.html) describes all the **Operations** `virt-sysprep` will perform, so they could fairly easily be transferred to a shell script, ansible playbook, or any other type of method.

**Links**

- [The source code for `guestfs-tools` shows specifically how `virt-sysprep` performs each operation](https://github.com/rwmjones/guestfs-tools/tree/59eeed778ca23111a8f0d329a65ead684c5aeb0c/sysprep)
- [Lots of people share their Linux sysprep scripts on Github](https://www.google.com/search?q=linux%20sysprep%20site%3Agithub.com)

Answer (score 0):

Sysprep is used to remove PC and user specific information from an image so that it will run on any system. Ubuntu is not like Windows, Ubuntu is already universal — it will already run on all systems.

If you want a completely golden, universal image, you can [download one from here](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop). The iso images will work on basically any compatible computer.